# Matplotlib set colormap for one axes object without changing default

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

How do I set the color cycler of one `matplotlib.pyplot.axes` object (or a figure alternatively) to a predefined colomap without changing the default as `plt.set_cmap` would do?

Say I'd like to use the 'tab20' colormap in one plot, using the following code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# something like ax.set_cmap('tab20')
ax.scatter([1,2,3],[2,1,3])
ax.scatter([1,2,3],[3,2,1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, the following does the trick:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_prop_cycle(cycler('color', plt.cm.tab20.colors))
ax.scatter([1,2,3],[2,1,3])
ax.scatter([1,2,3],[3,2,1])
```

It creates a color cycle with the colors from a colormap and assigns it to the axes object.

Comment: As `tab20` is a qualitative colormap,  you can simply retrieve the colors as `plt.cm.tab20.colors` - no need to know, how many distinct colors this colormap contains.